# Assign a Model type

Tags: sitecore-rocks

Following the [Getting started (Part 2)](https://youtu.be/dW_rQp9bMmE?t=1593), it shows assigning a defined Model Type to the Sitecore `Model.Item`.

However, when I open the `Model.Item` it does not seem to have a `Model.Type` input.

**Through Sitecore Rocks**
[image: No fields to show]

**And Sitecore Content Editor**
[image: No fields to show]

And **as expected**, when attaching the model to the Rendering:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@model Sitecore_first.Models.Car

<div>
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("Name")
</div>
```

I get the error:

> Inner Exception: Model definition item does not contain a model type
>   name. Item path: /sitecore/layout/Models/Car. Model type field name:
>   Model Type

What could cause the behavior of *no* `Model.Type` input field to define the Model class path?

---

### Specifications

- Sitecore rocks 2.0.39.0
- Visual studio 2015 Community
- Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Can you see the `Model Type` field if you view the item in Sitecore?

Comment: @RichardSeal Sadly not, it also shows the warning: "The current item does not contain any fields."

Comment: Sounds like your template is messed up. Check the template setup against a clean install of the same version of Sitecore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing a second instance, I copied the Model layout fields to my other instance.
Apparently, my current Model layout was completely empty.

Acter changing the values to the original values, all worked perfect!

[image: New values]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a model type for your model. It's the name of the class and name of the assembly. Something like : **namespace.yourclass,assembly**

Please see attached picture from Content Editor

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my problem is that the "Data" part does not show. I have also added a screenshot of the "Content Editor, to show this.

Comment: What sitecore version do you have? can you check if the template has same id like my template id ? {FED...

Comment: I have version 8.2 of Sitecore (rev 161221) and my template ID looks the same: `{FED6A14F-0D05-4E18-B160-17C0588A2005}`

Comment: looks like somebody delete that field, I verified a Sitecore 8.2 rev 161221 clean solution and  it exist. Can you verify recycle bin maybe you will find it there?